# How do you get "e.oldValue" if cell contents were pasted from another cell in Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Lots of people have asked how to get e.oldValue and e.value. However, how do I get the old value of a cell if the contents were overwritten via a "paste" of contents from another cell on the sheet? Here is what I know:

Let's take cell A1 with contents of "foo" and cell A2 with contents of "bar".

If A1 is overwritten by someone entering "bar" into it (including pasting from an external source): e.value = "bar" and e.oldValue = "foo".
If A1 is cleared, e.value = {"oldValue":"foo"}, e.oldValue = "foo".
If A1 is overwritten by someone copying A2 and pasting it into A1: e.value = {} and e.oldValue = {}. So we have to use e.range.getValue() to get our "new value" of "bar". However, how do I get the "oldValue"??

Yes, I know I can get it from cell A2, but how do I know what was overwritten in cell A1? That's what I want to know.

Right now my code for getting the two values I want to know is:

```
var newValue = (typeof e.value == "object" ? e.range.getValue() : e.value); 
var oldVlaue = e.oldValue;
```

Answer (score 5):

Please think of this as one of several workarounds. I thought that it might become a workaround by saving the data before editing. This sample script retrieves `oldValue` by using spreadsheet saved the data before editing. In order to use this sample script, please carry out as follows.

1. Please modify "backupfile" of `var backupfilename = "backupfile";` to an unique name.
2. Run a function of `init()`. By this, the backup file is created and the sheet that you want to retrieve `oldValue` is copied to it.
3. Install `onEdit(e)` as an installable trigger. The install method is below.

   - On script editor
   - Edit -> Current project's triggers
   - Click here to add one now.
   - Set "Run" to onEdit
   - Set "Events" to From spreadsheet, On edit

After these, when you edit the spreadsheet, `onEdit(e)` carries out retrieving data from both current spreadsheet and backup spreadsheet and then, the data of current spreadsheet is copied to the backup spreadsheet. So you can retrieve `oldValue` and `newValue` for the edited range. Also users that the spreadsheet is shared can retrieve `oldValue` and `newValue` through this sample script.

### Sample script :

```
var backupfilename = "backupfile"; // In this sample, this is a global variable.

function copyToo(srcrange, dstrange) {
    var dstSS = dstrange.getSheet().getParent();
    var copiedsheet = srcrange.getSheet().copyTo(dstSS);
    copiedsheet.getRange(srcrange.getA1Notation()).copyTo(dstrange);
    dstSS.deleteSheet(copiedsheet);
}

// At first, please run this function.
function init() {
  // Source
  var srcss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = srcss.getDataRange().getA1Notation();
  var srcrange = srcss.getRange(range);

  // Destination
  var backupfile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(backupfilename);
  var dstid = backupfile.hasNext()
    ? backupfile.next().getId()
    : SpreadsheetApp.create(backupfilename).getId();
  var dstrange = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dstid).getSheets()[0].getRange(range);

  copyToo(srcrange, dstrange);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('backupfileid', dstid);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var newValue = e.range.getValues();
  var dstid = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('backupfileid');
  var oldValue = SpreadsheetApp
    .openById(dstid)
    .getSheets()[0]
    .getRange(e.range.getA1Notation())
    .getValues();

  Logger.log("newValue %s", newValue)
  Logger.log("oldValue %s", oldValue)

  // Update backup file
  var range = e.source.getDataRange().getA1Notation();
  var srcrange = e.source.getRange(range);
  var dstrange = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dstid).getSheets()[0].getRange(range);
  copyToo(srcrange, dstrange);
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.